# Python numpy indexing for image array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to switch to python from matlab and i have this problem.

`imgMosaic` is a an numpy array.
You can see down there that the file resolution is `2548 x 4000`
i'm trying to access the first "mini-image" (resolution 28 x 40) from imgMosaic, but i'm getting a file with resolution `28x4000` instead of 
 `28x40` and i don't understand why.

```
imgMosaic = np.asarray(cv2.imread('../data/images/image.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))
print imgMosaic.shape
>> (2548, 4000, 3)
print imgMosaic[0:28][0:40][:]
>> (28, 4000, 3)
```

Comment: Use comma separated indexing : `imgMosaic[0:28,0:40,:]`

Comment: Thanks very much. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing could be modified as:

```
imgMosaic[:28, :40, :]
```

First 28 row element, first 40 column elements and all elements in the last axis.

```
imgMosaic[:28, :40, :].shape
>>> (28,40,3)
```